# ClassNotFoundException Raised When PySpark Read From Aws-S3 In Google Colab Environment

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, google-colaboratory

Google Colab research is a great to for testing python, data mining and deep learning, I want to run spark job on it based on pyspark and I got the Errors Raised When Reading From S3 In Google Colab Pyspark Script :

```java
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.json.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0):

0. create newnotebook and install the pyspark

```
!pip install pyspark # version 3.0.1
```

1. first download the aws related jar into the pyspark plugin folder,  here `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` is my python site-package folder and you can find yours via `import site; site.getsitepackages()`

```
! cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/jars && wget 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar'
! cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/jars && wget 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.4/hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar'
! cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/jars && wget 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.4/jets3t-0.9.4.jar'
```

2. config the pyspark session and context

```
SPARK_HOME = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/'

spark = SparkSession.\
        builder.\
        appName("pyspark-test").\
        config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "{0}/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar:{0}/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar".format(SPARK_HOME)).\
        config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "{0}/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar:{0}/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar".format(SPARK_HOME)).\
        getOrCreate()

# s3 configuration (actually i'm using digital ocean space which is s3 alternative)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "${access_key}")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "${secret_key}")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "${endpoint}")
```

3. read from s3

```py
# read from s3 server 
df = spark.read.json('s3a://path/test*.json'); 
df.show()
```

output

```
+---+---+----+
|  A|  B|   C|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  2|null|
|  1|  2|   3|
|  1|  2|null|
|  1|  2|null|
+---+---+----+
```

Enjoy guys.

Comment: I am following your sleps and I am using Python3.8
I am getting the error


'''RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number'''